# Why is there no special unit there for velocity/speed?

Tags: physics, units

Heat, time, and electrical current have separate units, namely, calorie, second and ampere, respectively. However, there is no special unit for velocity. We still use $\frac{\rm m}{\rm s}$. Why? Velocity has a separate significance more than current, right?

Comment: Because having different names synchronized with various units for length and time would clutter the everyday vocabulary, and m/s or mph are short enough. Heat, time and current are assigned [base units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_base_unit), and those must have special names. Since length and time are already assigned base units velocity's must be derived. Special names for derived units are redundant, but they do have [knots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_(unit)) in navigation where the context makes it worthwhile.

Comment: @Conifold a small correction: calorie isn't a base unit. Its use as a unit for heat is a result of the obsolete [Caloric Theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caloric_theory).

Comment: @BigBrother I meant temperature with kelvins, not calories.

Comment: If you want one word for a speed unit use knots. Knot is nautical mile per hour and a nautical mile is 1852 meters. As Conifold remarked, it is easier to use combination of units unless it gets too complicated. For example, $F= ma$ and the unit of force is "kilogram meter per second squared" or just say Newton.

Comment: In addition to seconds, units of time include: minutes, hours, days, weeks, fortnights, years, decades, centuries & millennia; but clever people decided that seconds would be a convenient division for scientific applications. For standardization, the unit of velocity, or speed, was decided as m/s for scientific applications, but we also use km/h for no scientific purposes & for very fast aircraft Mach (relative to the speed of sound) is also used.